# mathplotlib.finance error in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

So I was trying to create some candlestick charts in python using the code presented [here](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/stock-data-python.html). But when I run it I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py:136: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The finance module has been deprecated in mpl 2.0 and will be removed in mpl 2.2. Please use the module mpl_finance instead. warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
```

I of course tried replacing the line

```
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
```

with

```
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
```

but it still doesn't work.
Anyone know how to run the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DeprecationWarnings are generally only advisory warnings.  You should still be able to use the imported function (candlestick_ohlc in this case) and execute the rest of the code after it.

As far as why the mpl_finance import doesn't work -- did you install mpl_finance?  It appears to be at https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance .

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of matplotlib finance, with documentation, here:

https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/

Install with:  `pip install --upgrade mplfinance`

NOTE: The package name no longer has the dash or underscore: It is now mplfinance (not mpl-finance, nor mpl_finance)